# Row Delete Script - Comparison Between Dates Doesn't Work

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a VBA script to run through a set of rows and delete each row that is not equal to a certain date. The dates being compared are exactly the same, but when I run the script excel see none of the dates as matching. How do I get excel to recognize these dates are the same?

```
Sub test()

Dim X As Integer
Dim i As Long
Dim sh As Worksheet

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim k As Long
k = sh.Range("A1", sh.Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlDown).End(xlDown).End(xlUp)).Rows.Count

Range("A5:A" & k).Select

For X = 5 To k

    Dim DateValue As String
    Dim DateCheck As String

    DateValue = "A" & CStr(X)
    DateCheck = Range("B2").Value

        If DateValue <> DateCheck Then
            Selection.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Does "A5" equal a date? Or does the value in cell A5 have the date...

Comment: The proper way to find the last row would be `k = sh.Range("A" & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)`. Also, why not declare your dates as dates?

Comment: @JeremyThompson A5 holds a date, not exactly sure of the difference between your two question options but happy to clarify more

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the Cell Value of A5:

```
DateValue = Range("A" & CStr(X)).Value2
DateCheck = Range("B2").Value2
```

Also you haven't set the variable `i`, I think you want:

```
Selection.Rows(X).EntireRow.Delete
```

Two last tips when deleting, you will want to delete rows in reverse order (otherwise there will be gaps in the sequence):

```
For X = k To 5 Step -1
```

Or in forward order after deleting a row, decrement X, eg:

```
If DateValue = DateCheck Then
 Selection.Rows(X).EntireRow.Delete
 X = X - 1
End If
```

Comment: One adjustment I had to make, it should have been: "If DateValue <> DateCheck Then". Your response did fix the order in which the loop went through (bottom to top), but excel still won't recognize the correct dates. For example, if cell A12 = "2/1/2020 0:00" and cell B2 = "2/1/2020 0:00", excel will still delete row 12.

Comment: You're working with Dates as Strings, you should use Date types and get cell values with a cast if needed `DateCheck = CDate(Range("B2").Value2)`

Comment: Got it to work! After making that second set of edits, I realized after a bit of troubleshooting that excel was deleting the wrong when a date was different because `Selection.Rows(x).EntireRow.Delete` was telling excel to delete (X+1) rows down from A5 (the top of the excel range). Once I changed it to `Selection.Rows(x-4).EntireRow.Delete` it worked great. Thanks Jeremy!